# Full Calendar React icon component as custom header button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, react-icons

I'm trying to add an icon taken from the [react-icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/) package as a custom header button in my [Full Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons). Because the icons are exported from the package and not used as class names I can't seem to render that icon or any icons for that matter. I was hoping you could do something like this:

```
const customButtons = {
        custom1: {
            icon: <MdWatchLater />,
            click: function () {
                ('clicked the custom button!');
            }
        }
    }
```

but that throws an error. However, this approach doesn't work either (using font awesome icons), it just renders a square:

```
const customButtons = {
        custom1: {
            icon: "fa fa-lock",
            click: function () {
                ('clicked the custom button!');
            }
        }
    }
```

Has anyone tried this before? I don't mind which approach to take just as long as I can load an icon as a custom button.

**UPDATED**

Posting my Full Calendar component taking in the custom buttons props for reference:

**UPDATED**
Code snippet instead of photo:

```
<CustomCalendar
  customButtons={customButtons}
  header={{
     right: '',
     center: '',
     left: 'today prev,next custom1'
}} />
```

Comment: please don't post pictures of your code, it doesn't help anyone who might want to re-use it to amend it or make a demo. You've posted your other code as text correctly, so please so the same with your update at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: edited with code snippet instead, thanks.

Comment: No answer to this question yet? For jQuery I see this is supported as simple as http://jsfiddle.net/9por3Lod/1/